# linear gradient div using CSS3

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

Please help me how I can make div using css like below image path.

[image: Capture12.jpg]

Here is my code that is so far...
http://jsfiddle.net/L8FfE/

```
<table class="screenheader" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="padding-top: 5px;">
    <tr style="font-family: Calibri, Arial, Sans-Serif; font-size: 40pt; font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff; background: repeating-linear-gradient(180deg, #23538A , #A7CFDF 5px, #23538A  5px, #A7CFDF 10px);">
        <td width="100%" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
            <div id="meetingname" width="100%" style="padding-left: 20px; text-align: left;">
                HI Test
            </div>
        </td>
        <td width="100%" style="padding-left: 20px; text-align: left;">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can add images inline and you should put your markup in the question.

Comment: I have a  1 reputation so i can't put image. please help me to design div like my image

Comment: That's some horribly old school code you got there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793414/how-can-i-make-the-gradient-stops-in-a-css3-linear-gradient?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean (beside the colors, I can't get those right)?
http://jsfiddle.net/L8FfE/2/

Html:

```
<div id="background">
    <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#053F63), to(#105C97));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#053F63 0%, #105C97 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#053F63 0%, #105C97 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#053F63 0%, #105C97 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(#053F63 0%, #105C97 100%);
}
div#overlay {
    font-family: Calibri, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 40pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background:    -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(rgba(35, 83, 138, 1) 5px, rgba(167, 207, 223, 0) 5px, rgba(35, 83, 138, 1) 5px, rgba(167, 207, 223, 0) 10px);
    background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(rgba(35, 83, 138, 1) 5px, rgba(167, 207, 223, 0) 5px, rgba(35, 83, 138, 1) 5px, rgba(167, 207, 223, 0) 10px);
    background:         repeating-linear-gradient(rgba(35, 83, 138, 1) 5px, rgba(167, 207, 223, 0) 5px, rgba(35, 83, 138, 1) 5px, rgba(167, 207, 223, 0) 10px);
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(0.4, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(0.6, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)));
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
            mask-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
            mask-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
            mask-image:         linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not quite right. You'll need another div to achieve both the left gradient and vertical gradient. I've written this for Chrome only, and you'll also have to change the #colors to rgba, but you can see [in the JS fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/L8FfE/3/) it looks much more like the jpeg.

HTML

```
<div class="rightGradient">
    <div class="horizontal stripes"></div>
    <div class="topGradient"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.stripes {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 375px;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 6px;
}

.horizontal {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0f5b97 50%, transparent 50%, transparent);
}

.rightGradient {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 375px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #074166  20%, #0f5b97 70%);
}

.topGradient {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 375px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(286deg , #074166 -20%, transparent 70%);
}
```